PrimeNG orderlist cannot be resized by primeNG splitter
I have a primeNG orderlist inside a primeNG splitter tab. Unfortunately the orderlist contains some pretty long strings, which causes the splitter to not be able to resize the tab. It reaches its limit when the edge hits the end of the string and will not go further.
This can be seen in this Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-splitter-demo-chgeex?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
I tried truncating the string inside the orderlist by using text-overflow: ellipsis; in my css. While it works when i set the orderlist width manually to a specific width, I still cannot resize the tab via the splitter.
Does anyone have any idea how to make the splitter work properly again? Ideally I could make the tab as narrow as I want and have the parts of the string that are too long truncated.

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated

@NarenMurali Of course, I have edited my question :)

Try using the '\n' with template strings.
parameterList = [
    `This.is.a.very.long.list.item.and.I.have.multiple.ones,lalalala,\n I.want.to.truncate.that.word.when.,\nI.try.to.make.the.tab.narrower`,
  ];


While I agree that would make the orderList narrower, I cannot control the parameter names in real life, so that unfortunately is not an option for me.
